# heap corruption and mutex

Tags: c++, heap-memory, heap-corruption, boost-mutex

I have a serious bug in an application, and I try to understand what is going on..
I have some logs just before the crash.
I can't reproduce the bug simply.

the context :

```
Thread1:
void f()
{
    log(thread1_1)
    boost::lock_guard< boost::recursive_mutex > lock(mutexABC)
    log(thread1_2)
       -- eventually corruption heap could occur here
    log(thread1_3)
}

Thread2:
void f()
{
    log(thread2_1)
    boost::lock_guard< boost::recursive_mutex > lock(mutexABC)
       -- eventually corruption heap could occur here
    log(thread2_2)
}
```

In my logs (I am using LOG4CXX) I have the following sequence:

```
15:36:45,260  thread2_1
15:36:45,263  thread1_1
15:36:45,265  thread1_2
15:36:45,265  thread2_2

some GUI log thread3_*

15:36:45,276  //application crash
and no thread1_3 log before thread2_2!
```

How is it possible I log thread2_2 before thread1_3  ?
A lock can be unlocked due to a heap corruption without the program crash, and a second thread can acquire this lock and execute some code brefore application crash ?

I am under windows 7. my C++ program turn in release mode with compiler optimization turn on.

Comment: Is this mutex global/static (my point is - is it the same object for both threads)?

Comment: yes the mutex is defined inside an Object.This object is actually defined in a static/singleton obbject.

Comment: We need more information then. What are the mutexes? What does `LOCK` do? Etc.

Comment: I have edited (boost::mutex..)

Comment: Can you show the exact code of where you're creating the locks, not this pseudo code?

Comment: Did you run it under Valgrind to track down invalid memory use?

Comment: for begin use `std::mutex` and `std::unique_lock`